# Finite group and its proper subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, cardinals

Let G be a finite group and **S**, **T** are two  non empty subsets of G.
If  **G**#(not equal ) **ST** .
Show that |**G**|>=|**S**|+|**T**| .
I try it [image: trying to solve it.]

But not succeed

Comment: You can type the text of that image here, and that is always better. If you **really** must use an image, please at the very least rotate it. (And check for typos: your title has two)

Comment: Sorry, I am not use to with it's complicated typing so I put image here.  Forgot to rotate, sorry

Comment: This is then a good opportunity for you to practice typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G \ne ST$ there is a $g \in G; g \not \in ST$.

So for every $s\in S$, then $s^{-1}g\not \in T$. (Other wise $s*(s^{-1} g) = g\not \in ST$ but $s \in S$ so $s^{-1} g\not \in T$

These $s^{-1}g$ are distinct (i.e. if $s,t \in S; s \ne t$ then $s^{-1}g \ne t^{-1}g$).

So if $T^c = \{h \in G| h \not \in T\}$ then for every $s \in S$, $s^{-1}g \in T^c$ so $|S| \le |T^c|$.

So $|G| = |T| + |T^c| \ge |T| + |S|$.